# How can I specify a specific property value as a dependency in JSON Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I know I can do the following (from http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#schema-dependencies)

```
{
  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "name": { "type": "string" },
    "credit_card": { "type": "integer" }
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "credit_card": {
      "properties": {
        "billing_address": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["billing_address"]
    }
  }
}
```

However in my case I would only like credit card to depend on a required billing address when the credit card has a certain value. This is my attempt which didn't work:

```
{
  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "name": { "type": "string" },
    "credit_card": { "type": "integer" },
    "billing_address": { "type": "string" }
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "credit_card": {
      "enum": [100000000000],
      "properties": {
        "billing_address": {}
      },
      "required": ["billing_address"]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm working against the v4 draft.

Comment: You might get further using `oneOf` instead of `dependencies`.  Basically, you could say "Either (the credit card matches XXXXX and billing address is supplied) or (the credit card does not match XXXX)".

Comment: BTW, this would be a lot simpler with the proposed v5 keyword [`switch`](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/switch-%28v5-proposal%29).  However, v5 is not out yet, so that's not usable atm.